# Twitter Tweets PHP Error

Tags: php, twitter

I cannot include my tweets.php file, it gives this error when I try to include it with php: 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Documents\PHP\Projects\HassanTech\tweets.php on line 56

The source code for the file is:

```
    <?php

require_once('twitteroauth.php');


define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'REMOVED');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'REMOVED');
define('OAUTH_TOKEN', 'REMOVED');
define('OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET', 'REMOVED');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);


$content = "";
if (!isset($username)){
    $username = "Hassan_Tech";
}
if (!isset($number)){
    $number = 5;
}

$feed = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => $username, 'count' => $number));

//$url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name={$username}&count={$number}";
//$tweets = file_get_contents($url);
//$feed = new SimpleXMLElement($tweets);

function time_stamp($date){
    if (empty($date)){
        return "No date provided";
    }
    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");
    $now = time();
    $unix_date = strtotime($date);
    if (empty($unix_date)){
        return "Bad date";
    }
    if ($now > $unix_date){
        $difference = $now - $unix_date;
        $tense = "ago";
    } else {
        $difference = $unix_date - $now;
        $tense = "from now";
    }
    for ($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++){
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }
    $difference = round($difference);
    if ($difference != 1){
        $periods[$j] .= "s";
    }
    return "$difference $periods[$j] $tense";
}
for ($i = 0; $i <= $number-1; $i++){
    $status = $feed[$i]; // LINE 56
    //$status = $feed->status[$i];

    if (isset($status->id)){
        $id = $status->id;
    }

    $created_at = $status->created_at;
    $text = $status->text;
    $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $text);

    if (preg_match("/#(\w+)/", $text, $matches)){
        foreach($matches as $match){
            $match = str_replace("#", "", $match);
            $text = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/","<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q={$match}\">$0</a>",$text);
            $text = str_replace("<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q={$match}\">#","<span class=\"hash\">#</span><a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q={$match}\" target=\"_blank\">",$text);
        }
    }

    if (preg_match("/@(\w+)/", $text, $matches)) {
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            $match = str_replace("@", "", $match);
            $text = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/{$match}\">$0</a>", $text);
            $text = str_replace("<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/{$match}\">@", "<span class=\"at\">@</span><a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/{$match}\" target=\"_blank\">", $text);
        }
    }

    $content .= "<div class=\"status\"><div class=\"text\">{$text}</div>";

    if (isset($id)){
        $content .= "<div class=\"date\"><a href=\"http://twitter.com/Hassan_Tech/status/{$id}\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"".date("g:i A M jS", strtotime($created_at))."\">".time_stamp($created_at)."</a></div>";
    } else {
        $content .= "<div class=\"date\"><a href=\"\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"".date("g:i A M jS", strtotime($created_at))."\">".time_stamp($created_at)."</a></div>";
    }
    $content .= "</div>";
}

echo $content;
?>
```

Please help me out, thank you. I will really appreciate it. If you need any extra information, please let me know. Thank you. I know you guys are really smart and can surely help me out. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: You might not want to make you tokens, secrets, etc public.

Comment: Yeah, I did remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The response returned by twitter API is in json format, You need to convert it to array.

```
$feed = json_decode($feed);
```

The above line will convert json into an array. Use it after you get API response.

Comment: just add the above line below

Comment: $feed = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => $username, 'count' => $number));

Comment: I added the code below the $connection thingy line and now I get a shit load of errors. I get:

Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Documents\PHP\Projects\HassanTech\tweets.php on line 23

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\\tweets.php on line 64

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\\tweets.php on line 65

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tweets.php on line 64
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\\tweets.php on line 65
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tweets.php on line 64
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tweets.php on line 65

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tweets.php on line 64

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\\tweets.php on line 65
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tweets.php on line 64

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tweets.php

Comment: It works fine when I goto tweets.php but I am trying to do <?php include tweets.php; ?> in my home.php file.